# Including Fullpage.js in Wordpress (Or JS in General)

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming, fullpage.js

Well, venturing into new grounds, I've just hopped into Wordpress lately. After countless hours confused, it's safe to say I'm still confused, but less confused xD.

Anyway, I'm trying to include fullpage.js (Or any piece of javascript for that matter) into a Page, but I cannot get it to work. I just tried to use one of the examples from the fullpage.js folder, and I can't even get that to work. Here is what I have on the page:

```
<link href="http://wevolunteer.co/wp-content/themes/radiate/css/jquery.fullPage.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <link href="http://wevolunteer.co/wp-content/themes/radiate/css/example.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="http://wevolunteer.co/wp-content/themes/radiate/js/jquery.fullPage.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://wevolunteer.co/wp-content/themes/radiate/js/example.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var pepe = $.fn.fullpage({
                slidesColor: ['#1bbc9b', '#4BBFC3', '#7BAABE', 'whitesmoke', '#ccddff'],
                anchors: ['firstPage', 'secondPage', '3rdPage', '4thpage', 'lastPage'],
                menu: '#menu',
                scrollingSpeed: 1700
            });

        });

// ]]></script>

<select id="demosMenu"><option id="background" selected="selected">Choose Demo</option><option id="background">Background images</option><option id="backgroundVideo">Background video</option><option id="gradientBackgrounds">Gradient backgrounds</option><option id="looping">Looping</option><option id="noAnchor">No anchor links</option><option id="scrollingSpeed">Scrolling speed</option><option id="easing">Easing</option><option id="callbacks">Callbacks</option><option id="css3">CSS3</option><option id="continuous">Continuous scrolling</option><option id="normalScroll">Normal scrolling</option><option id="scrolling">Scroll inside sections and slides</option><option id="navigationV">Vertical navigation dots</option><option id="navigationH">Horizontal navigation dots</option><option id="fixedHeaders">Fixed headers</option><option id="apple">Apple iPhone demo (animations)</option></select>
<ul id="menu">
    <li data-menuanchor="firstPage"><a href="#firstPage">First slide</a></li>
    <li data-menuanchor="secondPage"><a href="#secondPage">Second slide</a></li>
    <li data-menuanchor="3rdPage"><a href="#3rdPage">Third slide</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="section " id="section0">
<h1>fullPage.js</h1>
Configure the scrolling speed!

<img alt="fullPage" src="imgs/fullPage.png" />

</div>
<div class="section" id="section1">
<div class="slide">
<div class="intro"><img alt="Cool" src="imgs/1.png" />
<h1>Slow scrolling speed</h1>
In case we want to make a site for old people, for example :)

</div>
</div>
<div class="slide">
<div class="intro"><img alt="Compatible" src="imgs/2.png" />
<h1>Landscape too</h1>
Also applied to landscape slides. Great uh?

</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="section" id="section2">
<div class="intro">
<h1>Slooooooww</h1>
Now you can try other demos!

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use [WP FullPage](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-fullpage/) to do that.

Comment: There's a wordpress theme linked in the [official fullpage.js site](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) as well.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't just copy that code into your page. There are special functions in WordPress to insert JS and CSS. The best would be to put this in your `functions.php`.

```
function register_fullpage() {
    wp_register_style( 'fullPage-css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/jquery.fullPage.css"' );
    wp_register_script( 'fullPage-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.fullPage.js' , array( 'jquery' ) );
    if ( is_page('your-page') ){
         wp_enqueue_style( 'fullPage-css' );
         wp_enqueue_script( 'fullPage-js' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'register_fullpage' );

function print_my_inline_script() {
       if ( wp_script_is( 'fullPage-js', 'done' ) ) { ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                 $(document).ready(function() {
                     var pepe = $.fn.fullpage({
                         slidesColor: ['#1bbc9b', '#4BBFC3', '#7BAABE', 'whitesmoke', '#ccddff'],
                         anchors: ['firstPage', 'secondPage', '3rdPage', '4thpage', 'lastPage'],
                         menu: '#menu',
                         scrollingSpeed: 1700
                     });

                });
            </script>
     <?php }
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'print_my_inline_script' );
```

How to add inline style is taken from [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/24863/47733).

More info can be found in the WordPress Codex:

[wp_register_style](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_style)

[wp_enqueue_style](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style)

[wp_register_script](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script)

[wp_enqueue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script)